# Simplify this expression: $25x^2 + 30x^3 - 35x^6$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I was thinking about simplifying this expression:

$$25x^2 + 30x^3 - 35x^6$$

Note that I don't mean just factoring $5x^2$ from it!

Comment: How exactly do you *solve* an expression?

Comment: What do you mean by "solving"? That's just an expression.

Comment: @KM101 I mean simplify it.

Comment: What kind of form would you call simpler than that?

Comment: "Simplifying" is vague and subjective (although not completely arbitrary; $2$ is clearly simpler than $\frac{105+95}{2\cdot 50}$). Do you mean "factor"?

Comment: And for factoring: over what field? There are two other real roots, other than the obvious repeated root at 0, and you can compute exact forms for them, but they're *hiddeous*. The two complex solutions are just as bad.

Comment: Ok, factor. You know I'm not English, I didn't know what should I call it.

Comment: Factoring out the $5x^2$ would be the right way to start.

Comment: Let me say an example: 4x^2 + 12x + 5 = (2x + 1)(2x + 5)

Comment: @amirali Yes, that's factoring. This one is *awful*, though. Like, really, unimaginably awful. Are you sure you want it factored?

Answer (score 3):

Your expression factors as $\frac{-5}{7}x^2a(x)b(x)c(x)$, where $a(x)$, $b(x)$, and $c(x)$ are, respectively,

$$\left(\!\!x\! -\!\! \sqrt{\!\sqrt[3]{\left(81\!+\!\sqrt{48561}\right)^2}\! -\! 10\sqrt[3]{42}}\!+\!\frac{\!\!\!\!\!\sqrt{\!10\sqrt[3]{\!42}\! -\!\! \sqrt[3]{\!\left(81\!+\!\sqrt{48561}\right)^2}\!+\!\!18\sqrt{\!\!\frac{2\left(81+\sqrt{48561}\right)}{\!\sqrt[3]{\!\left(81+\sqrt{48561}\right)^2}\! - 10\sqrt[3]{42}}}}}{\sqrt[6]{2^5}\sqrt[3]{21}\sqrt[6]{81+\sqrt{48561}}}\!\!\right)$$
and 
$$\left(\!\!x\! -\!\! \sqrt{\!\!\sqrt[3]{\!\left(\!81\!\!+\!\!\sqrt{\!48561}\!\right)^2}\!\! -\!\! 10\sqrt[3]{42}}\!-\!\!\frac{\!\!\!\!\!\sqrt{\!10\sqrt[3]{\!42} \!-\!\! \sqrt[3]{\!\!\left(81\!\!+\!\!\sqrt{\!48561}\right)^2}\!\!+\!\!18\sqrt{\!\!\frac{2\left(81+\sqrt{48561}\right)}{\!\sqrt[3]{\!\left(81+\sqrt{48561}\right)^2} - 10\sqrt[3]{42}}}}}{\sqrt[6]{2^5}\sqrt[3]{21}\sqrt[6]{81+\sqrt{48561}}}\right)$$

and 
$$\left(x^2 -\alpha x+\beta\right),$$

where $$\alpha=2\sqrt{\sqrt[3]{\left(81+\sqrt{48561}\right)^2}-10\sqrt[3]{41}}$$

and $$\beta\!=\!\!\sqrt[3]{\!\left(81\!\!+\!\!\sqrt{\!48561}\right)^2}\!\!-\!\!10\sqrt[3]{42}\! +\!\! \frac{\!\!\!\sqrt[3]{\!\left(81\!\!+\!\!\sqrt{\!48561}\right)^2}\!\!-\!\!10\sqrt[3]{42}\!+\!\!18\sqrt{\!\!\frac{2\left(81+\sqrt{48561}\right)}{\!\sqrt[3]{\left(81+\sqrt{48561}\right)^2}-10\sqrt[3]{42}}}}{\sqrt[3]{2^5}\sqrt[3]{21^2}\sqrt[3]{81+\sqrt{48561}}}.$$

Comment: You have warned OP above, so the shock was mitigated.....

Comment: Is this an output of a program?

Comment: @kelalaka The initial factorisation was, yes. I LaTeXed it manually.

Comment: +1 for the latex

Comment: Could you please share your solution?

Comment: @amirali I told a computer to find the roots of the equation $5 + 6x - 7x^4 = 0$. With those in hand (call them $a,b,c,d$), the equation then factorises (over the complex numbers) as $(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) = 0$, and hence your expression factorises as $\frac{-5}{7}x^2(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d)$. However, $c$ and $d$ were not real, so I combined those two factors into $(x^2 - (c+d)x + cd)$, giving the factorisation over the reals.